# Laravel orderByRaw is removing results from union query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am running this query in a project where I am having "meta_competitions" and "primary_events" that is going to merge together into a result where they do not overlap by primary_event_meta_competitions having the primary_event_id of the current primary_event.

Everything is working as expected in the query itself, we are getting the results we want. But when we add the orderByRaw() everything except one result is removed of the meta_competitions.

I have tried running the query I get when i am running "->toSql()" instead of ->get() of the query in pure sql and there everything works as expected.

```
$metaCompetitions = DB::table('meta_competitions')
    ->select('meta_competitions.name as name', 'sports.name as sport', 'meta_competitions.id', 'meta_competitions.country')
    ->where('meta_competitions.name', 'LIKE', "%{$string}%")
    ->whereIn('meta_competitions.sport_id', [1, 3, 4, 9])
    ->join('sports', 'sports.id', '=', 'meta_competitions.sport_id');

$leagues = DB::table('primary_events')

    ->select('primary_events.name as name', 'sports.name as sport', 'primary_events.id', 'primary_events.country')
    ->where('primary_events.name', 'LIKE', "%{$string}%")
    ->whereIn('primary_events.sport_id', [1, 3, 4, 9])
    ->whereNull('primary_event_meta_competitions.primary_event_id')
    ->leftJoin('primary_event_meta_competitions', 'primary_event_meta_competitions.primary_event_id', '=', 'primary_events.id')
    ->leftJoin('sports', 'sports.id', '=', 'primary_events.sport_id')

    ->union($metaCompetitions)

    ->orderByRaw(
        'CASE
            WHEN name = ? THEN 1
            WHEN name LIKE ? THEN 2
            WHEN name LIKE ? THEN 4
            ELSE 3
          END', [$string, "{$string}%", "%{$string}"]
    )
    ->get();

    dd($leagues);
```

The query that I get from ->toSql() and that works for me is the following:

```
(select `primary_events`.`name` as `name`, `sports`.`name` as `sport`, `primary_events`.`id`, `primary_events`.`country` from `primary_events` 
left join `primary_event_meta_competitions` on `primary_event_meta_competitions`.`primary_event_id` = `primary_events`.`id` 
left join `sports` on `sports`.`id` = `primary_events`.`sport_id` 
where `primary_events`.`name` LIKE '%Allsvenskan%' and `primary_events`.`sport_id` in (1, 3, 4, 9) and `primary_event_meta_competitions`.`primary_event_id` is null) 
union (select `meta_competitions`.`name` as `name`, `sports`.`name` as `sport`, `meta_competitions`.`id`, `meta_competitions`.`country` from `meta_competitions` 
inner join `sports` on `sports`.`id` = `meta_competitions`.`sport_id` 
where `meta_competitions`.`name` LIKE '%Allsvenskan%' and `meta_competitions`.`sport_id` in (1, 3, 4, 9)) 
order by CASE
                WHEN name = 'Allsvenskan' THEN 1
                WHEN name LIKE 'Allsvenskan%' THEN 2
                WHEN name LIKE '%Allsvenskan' THEN 4
                ELSE 3
              END
```

My tables looks like:

```
meta_competitions
id:name:sport_id:country

primary_events
id:name:sport_id:country

sports
id:name

primary_event_meta_competitions
primary_event_id:meta_competition_id
```

Comment: If you dont find the answer, use `DB::Select()` with the raw sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was kind of an odd issue. When I did not orderByRaw but used a selectRaw to a custom column and sorted that column everything worked as expected.

Why is this different at all?

```
    $metaCompetitions = DB::table('meta_competitions')
        ->select('meta_competitions.name as name', 'sports.name as sport', 'meta_competitions.id', 'meta_competitions.country')
        ->selectRaw('CASE
                WHEN meta_competitions.name = ? THEN 1
                WHEN meta_competitions.name LIKE ? THEN 2
                WHEN meta_competitions.name LIKE ? THEN 4
                ELSE 3
              END AS order_col', [$string, "$string%", "%$string"] )
        ->selectRaw("'meta_competition' AS type")
        ->where('meta_competitions.name', 'LIKE', "%{$string}%")
        ->whereIn('meta_competitions.sport_id', [1, 3, 4, 9])
        ->join('sports', 'sports.id', '=', 'meta_competitions.sport_id');

    $leagues = DB::table('primary_events')

        ->select('primary_events.name as name', 'sports.name as sport', 'primary_events.id', 'primary_events.country')
        ->selectRaw('CASE
                WHEN primary_events.name = ? THEN 1
                WHEN primary_events.name LIKE ? THEN 2
                WHEN primary_events.name LIKE ? THEN 4
                ELSE 3
              END AS order_col', [$string, "$string%", "%$string"] )
        ->selectRaw("'league' AS type")
        ->where('primary_events.name', 'LIKE', "%{$string}%")
        ->whereIn('primary_events.sport_id', [1, 3, 4, 9])
        ->whereNull('primary_event_meta_competitions.primary_event_id')
        ->leftJoin('primary_event_meta_competitions', 'primary_event_meta_competitions.primary_event_id', '=', 'primary_events.id')
        ->leftJoin('sports', 'sports.id', '=', 'primary_events.sport_id')

        ->union($metaCompetitions)

        ->orderBy('order_col')

        ->get();
```